# Liquibase with a custom classloader (and a custom protocole)

Tags: liquibase

In my application I use a custom classloader and a custom protocole (for example `myProtocole:`).

The problem is that Liquibase, to find some of its implementation classes, uses its own way  (in `liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver`). Specifically `protected void find(PackageScanFilter test, String packageName, ClassLoader loader, Set<Class<?>> classes)` contains something like :

```
if (urlPath.startsWith("file:")) {
// ....
if (url.toString().startsWith("bundle:") || urlPath.startsWith("bundle:")) {
// ...
if (urlPath.startsWith("http:") || urlPath.startsWith("https:")
                        || urlPath.startsWith("sonicfs:") || urlPath.startsWith("vfs:") || urlPath.startsWith("vfszip:")) {
```

Of course, it doesn't understand my custom `myProtocole:` protocole! So it won't find the required implementation classses, even the default ones which are included in the Liquibase jar `liquibase-core-XXX.jar`, .jar *that has to be loaded using my custom protocole though*.

My question : is there a way to tell Liquibase to use its default implementation classes, without it to have to search for other implementation classes? I do not need to extends or customize any of the base Liquibase classes, I just need Liquibase to work in my application!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by extending `DefaultPackageScanClassResolver`, in which I added my custom classloader and overrided the `find` method.

I wish it would be simpler though.

Comment: There has been some changes with how the DefaultPackageScanClassResolver works with the new 3.2.0 release. It may work better now without needing your subclass